# How to use query string in fetch post?

Tags: reactjs, authentication, fetch-api

Newbie here. Building a React site. I'm struggling to get my authentication to go through a fetch post. It keeps returning "No such user" error, but when I have verified the user DOES exist.

I'm using passport on the backend.

```
const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    const data = {
      Username: username,
      Password: password
    };

    fetch('https://cthulhuflix.onrender.com/login', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: new URLSearchParams(JSON.stringify(data))
    })
    .then ((response) => response.json())
    .then ((data) => {
      console.log('Login response: ', data);
      if (data.user) {
        onLoggedIn(data.user, data.token);
      } else {
        alert('Dave\'s not here! No such user.');
      }
    })
    .catch((e) => {
      alert('Something went wrong');
    });
};
```

Comment: Maybe it's backend's fault?

Comment: What does `console.log('Login response: ', data);` emit

Comment: Hi Evert, It emits the .catch error message and shows user: false

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I ended up with:

```
export const LoginView = ({ onLoggedIn }) => {
  const [username, setUsername] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
  
  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    const data = {
      Username: username,
      Password: password
    };

    fetch('https://cthulhuflix.onrender.com/login?' + new URLSearchParams(data).toString(), {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify(data)
    }).then ((response) => {
      if (response.ok) {
        onLoggedIn(username);
      } else {
        alert('Login failed');
      }
    });
  };
```